# I've recently built a desktop computer and am having trouble connecting a dual monitor

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon

I've already set up one monitor as my main one with and HDMI cable from my graphics card and i'm wanting to know how to use the VGA port from my motherboard to connect another monitor. (i'm currently running on windows 10)

Comment: Chances are your onboard graphics are disabled when a PCI graphics card has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

depends on your hardware. check if:

1. your cpu has a integrated gpu.
2. your bios is set to use pci gpu and integrated gpu (depend on hardware)
3. use integrated gpu and dedicated together, sometimes runs into problems so if you can is much better use an hdmi to vga adapter.